# Border Radius in internet explorer

Tags: css

I had implemented border radius for my css file and iam also using ie-css.htc script for its working internet explorer and the border radius is working fine in internet explorer in my localhost,But when i upload the files to a windows server border radius is not working in internet explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you reference your .htc file correct? `*.htc` files should be referenced relative to your html document, *not* relative to your stylesheet.

If this won't resolve your issue, could you provide us with a code sample, or the URL where you've deployed your website to?

Comment: i had added .htc file reference in my css file

Comment: I know, but how? `behavior: url(../file.htc)` or `behavior: url(/css/file.htc)`? Or something else?

Comment: i had placed file.htc in my css folder and and i had mentioned it in my css file as behaviour:url(ie-css3.htc)

Comment: so it should be behavior: url(style/file.htc)

Comment: but after adding this file as i mentioned above in my register.css file border radius is working fine in Internet Explorer in my localhost

Comment: what @Gijs says: if you reference your stylesheet as follows: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/stylesheet.css" />` your should reference your htc file as behavior: `url(styles/file.htc)`.

Comment: is it to be mentioned in my css file or html file

Comment: like said before: mentioned in your css, relative to your html

Comment: @user1569674 So you are 100% sure that internet explorer *actually* loads your htc file?

Comment: okay thanks for ur help, i had mentioned in my css file and i had given correct path, is it any way like inspect element in IE8

Comment: Can you at least try to put styles/ before your htc files in your register.css? for example: behavior: url(styles/ie-css3.htc);

Comment: i had specified my url as  behavior: url(styles/ie-css3.htc) also but no change